# Slow MongoDB query and Schema design

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, nosql

I designed a Schema for a client entity with all the related entities embedded instead of the being in a separate collection. The schema for mi `Client` collection looks something like this:

```
{
  id: '123-123-123',
  shops: [
    { id: '123-123-123', name: 'Shop 1', location: 'USA' },
    { id: '321-321-321', name: 'Shop 2', location: 'England' },
    //...

  ],
  paymentMethods: [
    { id: '123-123-123', name: 'PayPal', kind: 'e-money' },
    { id: '321-321-312', name: 'Bank of America', kind: 'bank' },
    //...
  ]
}
```

Now, my other collection is called `Customers`, with a Schema similar to this:

```
{
  id: '123-123-123',
  clientId: '123-123-123',
  name: 'John Doe',
  purchases: [
    { shopId: '123-123-123', paymentMethodId: '123-123-123', amountsDebited: [ 
      { currency: 'USD', amount: 999 }, { currency: 'EUR', amount: 111 } 
    ] },
    { shopId: '321-312-312', amountsDebited: [ 
      { currency: 'USD', amount: 999, paymentMethodId: '321-321-312', },
      { currency: 'EUR', amount: 111, paymentMethodId: '321-321-312', } 
    ]},

  ]
}
```

What I would need finally need to get is a CSV with the following data/format:

`Shop name,Client name, Payment method name, amount, currency`

So basically what I have to do is to unwind `purchases` and `amountsDebited`.

What I have done to get this information (and it works, although slowly) is:

```
[
    {
        '$unwind': {
            'path': '$purchases', 
            'preserveNullAndEmptyArrays': False
        }
    }, {
        '$unwind': {
            'path': '$purchases.amountsDebited', 
            'preserveNullAndEmptyArrays': False
        }
    }, {
        '$lookup': {
            'from': 'Client', 
            'let': {
                'paymentMethodId': '$purchases.amountsDebited.paymentMethodId', 
                'shopId': '$purchases.shopId', 

            }, 
            'pipeline': [
                {
                    '$match': {
                        '$expr': {
                            '$eq': [
                                '$id', '$$clientId'
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                }, {
                    '$unwind': '$shops'
                }, {
                    '$match': {
                        '$expr': {
                            '$eq': [
                                '$$shopId', '$shops.id'
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                }, {
                    '$unwind': '$paymentMethods'
                }, {
                    '$match': {
                        '$expr': {
                            '$eq': [
                                '$$paymentMethodId', '$paymentMethods.uuid'
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                }
            ], 
            'as': 'metaData'
        }
    }
]
```

I realize that because I have that information as subdocuments, the lookup is not possible to do the lookup in a straight forward way. Instead, I have to unwind and "filter" the subdocuments, which I am sure isn't optimal.

So, my question would be, can I optimize my query somehow and keep the current Schema?

Or should a separate the `shops` and `paymentMethods` into a separate collection and do a normal lookup?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I think the slowness is because the full client document is fetched and its shops and payment methods unwound for every single payment in the customers collection.

One possible improvement would be to denormalize the data a bit.  If you were to add the shop name and payment method name to the customer document, the lookup would be completely unnecessary.

Comment: I evaluated doing something like that, but then every time a shop name changes, should a write potentially millions of documents?

Comment: That is very true.  But compare the total overhead along with the frequency of it happening: write millions of documents when a shop name changes a few times per year, or read millions of extra documents every time this report runs.